# What is an answer and what is a comment: with an example (?)

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, not-an-answer

Looking the question here: [How do I include a pipe | in my linux find -exec command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307015/how-do-i-include-a-pipe-in-my-linux-find-exec-command) , RolfW.Rasmussen's answer appears quickly to be a nice one, as well as fiolo's. Which is better, not a point of discussion I want to raise here.

Anyway, look at raphaelfournier's answer. It is a 6-times upvoted comment. Cannot be anything else: *"I was in the case of the original poster"* and *(the other solution) "is to be mentionned and up-voted"*.

I raised a flag, a moderator came and it was declined as "moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". I really don't care about my flag being disputed here, but that blatantly low-quality crap like that, shall be left on the site, I cannot understand, and I cannot accept. Why, because it was upvoted?

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy only partially related to this one; also by copying someone else answer in his own, as it is and without adding nothing, may  break the copyright.